# mod_rewrite separate two numbers with hyphen/dash

Tags: mod-rewrite

To secure my URL I am trying to add some additional numeric values to the user's id using `mod_rewrite`.

I have this URL

```
https://www.domain.com/dashboard.php?userempid=48&hgid=45
```

I need to rewrite the above URL to

```
https://www.domain.com/1848-6245.html
```

This is what I tried and it never works

```
RewriteRule ^18([0-9])-62([0-9]).html$ dashboard.php?userempid=$1&hgid=$2 [NC,L]
```

Please Help!

Answer (score 0):

Change your rule adding a plus:

```
RewriteRule ^18([0-9]+)\-62([0-9]+).html$ dashboard.php?userempid=$1&hgid=$2 [NC,L]
```